# Preprocess-Query to find number of pairs containing a number X

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures

Formally we are given N pairs of rational numbers . We want to somehow preprocess on this data so as to answer queries like "Find number of pairs which contain a given rational number X" .
By ' a pair contains X' i mean [2,5] contains 3 & so on.

At worst , expected time for each query should be O(log N) or O(sqrt(N)) (or anything similair better than O(N)) & preprocessing should be at worst O(N^2) .

My approach:
I tried sorting pairs , first by first number & break ties by second number [First nos in pair < Second nos in pair]. Then applying a lower_bound form of binary search reduces the search space but now i can't apply another Binary search in this search space since pairs are sorted first by first nos. so after reducing search space i have to linearly check . This is again having worst case O(N) per query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should try to make the ranges disjoint. For example ranges `[1 5],[2 6],[3 7]` will result in disjoint ranges of `[1 2],[2 3],[3 5],[5 6],[6 7]` and for each range you should save in how many original ranges it was present. Like this

```
1-------5      // original ranges
  2------6
    3------7
1-2, 2-3, 3-5, 5-6, 6-7  // disjoint ranges
 1     2    3    2    1  // number of presence of each range in original ranges
```

You can do this by a sweep line algorithm in `O(NlogN)`. After that You can use the method you described by sorting the ranges by its start and then for each query finding the `lower_bound` of `Xi` and printing the `presence` count of that range. For example in this case if the query is `4` you can find the range `3-5` by a binary search and then the result is `3` because the `presence` of range `3-5` is equal to `3`.

Comment: *O(N log N) line sweep . Thanks!